# rails 4 better way to write rails update and find record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following rails active model

```
def update_status
    post = Post.find params[:id]
    post_status = post.update_attributes(status: status, user_id: user)
    if post_status
       post = Post.find params[:id]
       status = post.status
       user = Post.user_id
    end
end
```

In the above code I wrote `find post` two times Is there any better way to do it. Any suggestions?

**Edit-1:**

My update code in `post_controller.rb`

```
post_status = post.update_attributes(status: status, user_id: user, approved_at: DateTime.now.to_time)
```

and my link which updates status in view is

```
<%= link_to edit_post_path(post, {status: 1}), class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm post-status', method: :get, remote: true do %>change status<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in Rails 4 way like this, I didnt find any reason of finding post two times, where() is preferred over find as find() has been deprecated in rails 4, and i find no use of local variables `status` and `user`. If you want to use them in views, use instance variables instead

```
def update_status
    post = Post.where("id =?", params[:id]).first
    post.user_id = user
    post.status = status
    post.save
end
```

Comment: can you tell me what you exactly want to do?

Comment: In the above code user_id is a session value. will post_params will work for session values to update

Comment: see the updated code, you don't have to reassign values to `user` and `status`, the values will be there as they were before